# Parse columns and data from single column table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table `@tbl_rawData` where I loaded data from a very dynamic file (no fix position of columns), so I loaded the whole file in one column only.

I need to fetch the required column and corresponding data for each column.

I am interested in `ID`, `customername`, `prodname` and `regency` columns as maintained in `@tbl_collist` table  but in future, maybe I need more columns then I would insert more column name in `@tbl_collist`.

```
declare @tbl_rawData table (fileData varchar(max))
insert into @tbl_rawData 
    (fileData)
values
    ('#Columns: ID|customername|addresss|agency|prodname|valuation|regency|ceptam|agan|yaha|citr'),
    ('11|jeev|a-161 kv|criu|uio|1800000|abap|yes|no|1000|200|'),
    ('12|poon|b-278 abv|criu|uio|50000|pyt|yes|no|2700|300|')

declare @tbl_collist table (colName varchar(100))
insert into @tbl_collist 
    (colName)
values
    ('ID'),
    ('customername'),
    ('prodname'),
    ('regency')
```

I want to have an output like below.

```
 id   customername   prodname    regency 
 11   jeev           uio         abap 
 12   poon           uio         pyt
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: My sql server version is 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of [dbo.DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) then:

```
-- Sample Data
declare @tbl_rawData table (fileData varchar(max));
insert into @tbl_rawData (fileData)
values
    ('#Columns: ID|customername|addresss|agency|prodname|valuation|regency|ceptam|agan|yaha|citr'),
    ('11|jeev|a-161 kv|criu|uio|1800000|abap|yes|no|1000|200|'),
    ('12|poon|b-278 abv|criu|uio|50000|pyt|yes|no|2700|300|');

declare @tbl_collist table (colName varchar(100))
insert into @tbl_collist (colName)
values('ID'),('customername'),('prodname'),('regency');

-- Solution
WITH Split AS
(
  SELECT      s.ItemNumber
  FROM        @tbl_rawData AS t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.fileData,'|') AS s
  JOIN        @tbl_collist AS c ON s.Item = c.colName 
                                OR (ItemNumber = 1 AND c.colName = 'ID')
  WHERE       t.fileData LIKE '#%'
)
SELECT 
  ID           = MAX(IIF(s.ItemNumber = 1, s.Item, NULL)),
  customername = MAX(IIF(s.ItemNumber = 2, s.Item, NULL)),
  prodname     = MAX(IIF(s.ItemNumber = 5, s.Item, NULL)),
  regency      = MAX(IIF(s.ItemNumber = 7, s.Item, NULL))
FROM        @tbl_rawData AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.fileData,'|') AS s
WHERE       t.fileData NOT LIKE '#%'
  AND       s.ItemNumber IN (SELECT split.ItemNumber FROM split)
GROUP BY    t.fileData;
```

**Returns:**

```
ID  customername  prodname  regency    
--- ------------- --------- -----------
11  jeev          uio       abap
12  poon          uio       pyt
```